# Learning rails and AJAX. How do I load a div via ajax and then toggle hiding/showing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, toggle

I'm doing my first Ruby on Rails project.  I am working on a project where the user can add a new message.  Then they can add updates to this message like a thread.  I've got it all written and now I'm going back and applying some AJAX.  I want to show just the main message when the page first loads.  Then when I click a link I want an AJAX event to fire that populates a div with all the updates to the message.  Then I want this same link to toggle hiding and showing the div.

I've made a submit button to fire the ajax and get back the updates using form_remote_tag.  I've also created a separate link to toggle the hiding using $(div_id).toggle();.  But now I'm stuck on how to combine these two things into one all purpose link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Javascript function that behaves differently based on the state of your content.

```
function content_mgr(content_div) {
   // is $(content_div) empty?
   //     submit form
   // else
   //     $(content_div).toggle();
}
```

And in your template:

```
<%= button_to_function "Super Button", "content_mgr('div_id');" %>
```

Comment: I did something very similar to this.  Thanks for the advice